# Auth with NuxtJS and Sanctum on Valet setup

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js, laravel-sanctum, laravel-valet

Hours wasted but still can't understand why I'm only able to run authorization with NuxtJS and Laravel Sanctum only through `http://localhost`, every other time I'm getting `419 token mismatch`.

I know that for authorization to work properly frontend and backend should be on the same TLD *.tld.test my setup is (I even went further and made the same domain but the different port to serve FE/BE, doesn't help too, also countless other combinations):

```
FE app -> app.backend.test:3000
BE app -> backend.test
```

I have all settings related to CORS, no CORS errors here.

Other important settings:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
```

In sanctum.php

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1,backend.test,backend.test:3000,app.backend.test,app.backend.test:3000',
        env('APP_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
    ))),
```

By the way, I'm using Valet, so every *.test is pointed to 127.0.0.1 automatically through dnsmasq, If that matters somehow.

And the only way I can run this thing is to use localhost:3000 and localhost:8000 by running PHP artisan serve and changing above mentioned settings to "localhost".

So http://localhost:3000 is nuxt serve and http://localhost:8000 is PHP artisan serve.

Comment: did you figure this out?